# Allow .htaccess edition

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permissions

I'm trying to make my wordpress site more secure, so I need to add some rules on my .htaccess. But suddenly, I made the following mistake:

```
RewriteRule ^(php\.ini|\.htaccess) - [NC,F]
```

And now I can't write more rules in it. Everytime I try to edit, I get the message:

> Error: Forbidden file edition: //httpdocs/.htaccess: filemng: Error
>   occurred during /bin/cp command.

I already tried to:

- Delete the file and create again
- Replace the code
- Upload from my computer...
- Replace via SSH

All in vain.
When I used SSH, the old code (standard htaccess generated by wordpress) was there, but somehow the rule is still applied on the file. I can't edit it.
What can I do?

Thanks & sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I am assuming you are trying to edit it using cPanel? In which case to edit it you will have to manually edit the file on the machine where it is hosted. Do you have access?

Comment: @Shaunak, It's Plesk. I forgot to mention that I did a replace via SSH, but when I opened again, the old code (standard htaccess generated by wordpress) was there. The line "RewriteRule ^(php\.ini|\.htaccess) - [NC,F]" was gone, but somehow the rule is still applied on the file.

Comment: Try to remove the `#BEGIN Wordpress` and `#END Wordpress` lines and see if you still have the issue.

Comment: @vard Yep, I still have the issue :(

Comment: Could you check on the file permission through ssh? (and owner / group as well)

Comment: @vard, it's usernameHere:psacln. I tried to change to apache user, root user... Same problem :T

Comment: Is it the same permissions user/group as your php files for instance?

Comment: @vard, Yes, same permissions. Very strange, huh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to connect to your webserver with filezilla or something else.

Here an example of the basic .htaccess: [Wordpress .htaccess](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question, and this won't help me :(

Comment: Did you try to rename the file and create a new .htaccess file? Maybe this will help..